# ORA-01722: invalid number exception while using "escape"

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I have query with special characters and I am using "escape" in it. It works fine for single filter but multiple filters it gives ORA-01722: invalid number exception. Example:

```
    <some query> 
    and this_.NAME like  '%<some_string>%' escape '\'   
    and this_.ID IN ()
```

this will throw exception.
But, If I change order, like below, it works:

```
    <some query> 
    and this_.ID IN ()
    and this_.NAME like  '%<some_string>%' escape '\'
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that both queries returned **all** rows? Some GUI tools return first 100 or 500 rows, but not the whole set. If you navigate to the end (or, simply, use `SELECT DISTINCT`), you might notice that the second query (with the "changed order") fails as well.

Comment: @Littlefoot, first query fails but second return all rows.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Just to make sure: try to remove (comment) the `and this_.NAME like ...` and run the query; what happens? Then comment the `and this_.ID ...` and un-comment the `and this_.NAME ...` and run it again. Why? To find out which one of those conditions is responsible for the error & narrow further investigation.

Comment: If I put single condition like either this_.NAME or this_.ID it works.

Comment: I don't see what `escape` has to do with it. Is there even a '\' in your wildcard?

Comment: We can say with some confidence that what you think is happening is not actually happening. In reality there is some collision between the values you have in your filters and the data in your restricting columns. You haven't posted a reproducible test case so there's nothing more we can do to help you. You need to diagnose your database yourself. If you want more help you need to post some sample data **and** examples of the filters which work and those that hurl.

Comment: There was issue (I am looking into it) with hardcoded values provider in hibernate restrictions. I used placeholder ( ? ) , so its working fine now. This was causing issue: like  '%<some_string>%' now I a m using:  like ?.

Answer (score 0):

> It works fine for single filter but multiple filters it gives ORA-01722: invalid number exception.

It should work for multiple filter predicates.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 cola, 'a%b%c' colb FROM dual
  3  UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2 cola, 'abc' colb FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT * FROM DATA
  7  WHERE colb LIKE '%\%b\%%' ESCAPE '\'
  8  AND cola IN (1,2);

      COLA COLB
---------- -----
         1 a%b%c
```